# Filtering list of objects based on attribute

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have 4 objects.

```
class MyObject:
    def __init__(self, id: int, result_name: str):
        self.id = id
        self.result = Result(result_name)


class Result:
    def __init__(self, name: str):
        self.name = name

object1 = MyObject(1, 'A')
object2 = MyObject(2, 'A')
object3 = MyObject(3, 'B')
object4 = MyObject(4, 'B')
```

They're stored in a tuple:

```
x_ids = (object1, object2, object3, object4)
```

I want bases on parameters:

```
[x.result.name for x in x_ids]  
>> ("A", "A", "B", "B")
```

Have list of resulting list, just two objects with "A", and "B" attribute

```
   result = (object(1or2), object(3or4))
```

How can I  achieve it with list comprehensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can that using `reduce` from `functools`.

Let's start by creating the sample data:

```
class MyObject:
    def __init__(self, id: int, result_name: str):
        self.id = id
        self.result = Result(result_name)


class Result:
    def __init__(self, name: str):
        self.name = name

object1 = MyObject(1, 'A')
object2 = MyObject(2, 'A')
object3 = MyObject(3, 'B')
object4 = MyObject(4, 'B')

x_ids = (object1, object2, object3, object4)
```

Now we perform the list comprehension:

```
from functools import reduce
result = tuple(reduce(lambda t, s: {**t, s.result.name: s}, x_ids, {}).values())
```

Result:

```
(object2, object4)
```

The list comprehension (reduce) starts with an empty dict `{}`. Each iteration, an entry from `x_ids` is passed to the lambda function as `s` and the current state of the dict is passed as `t`. The dict gets updated by adding the object `s` with key `s.result.name`. If that key already exists, the entry will be overwritten - this filters out objects with the same result name. The result is a dict: `{'A':object2, 'B':object4}`. The result is then converted into the required tuple format.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this very easily with a set:

```
class MyObject:
    def __init__(self, id_, result_name):
        self.id_ = id_
        self.result = Result(result_name)


class Result:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

object1 = MyObject(1, 'A')
object2 = MyObject(2, 'A')
object3 = MyObject(3, 'B')
object4 = MyObject(4, 'B')

T = (object1, object2, object3, object4)

S = {o.result.name for o in T}

print(S)
```

**Output:**

```
{'A', 'B'}
```

**Note:**

You could obviously convert the set to a list if that's what you need.

Use of *id* not a great idea as a variable name

Comment: This is not necessarily correct, question was to return objects itself